# Proving a binary operation is not associative given a latin square

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, binary-operations, associativity, latin-square

Given a Latin square

[image]

how would one tell if the operation is associative without trying every combination? Or is there something to look for that would at least limit the amount of combinations I have to try?

In this case I found $(bb)b \ne b(bb)$ but I struggled quite a bit.

Comment: See number 27 of Matousek's *33 Miniatures* https://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~matousek/

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That looks very interesting! However I don't think an algorithm like *that* would be any quicker than the naive approach for most people :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, it is easy to see that $e$ is an identity.

**Lemma:** Given a latin square with an identity, the operation is associative if and only if the latin square is the table of a group.

This is immediate. Indeed $\Leftarrow$ is obvious.

For $\Rightarrow$ associativity and identity are given, and it is immediate that latin square implies inverses.

\qed

For the given table it is trivial to see it is not coming from a group, as any group with 5 elements is cyclic thus commutative, and your square is not.

In general, given a larger latin square it may be hard to decide if it is the table of a group or not.

Comment: Yes, I agree that (given knowledge of Lagrange's theorem) this particular case would be trivial, but I was asking how to find an *example* of non-associativity. However your last sentence answers that question, thanks!

Comment: It's almost as easy to see that a Latin square is associative if and only if it's the table of a group. Therefore, if there is no identity, it can't be associative.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about group theory (but something about permutations). Rename your Latin Square into the isomorphic one under the bijection:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&e\mapsto 1 \\
&a\mapsto 2 \\
&b\mapsto 3 \\
&c\mapsto 4 \\
&d\mapsto 5 \\
\end{alignat}
Then you get to:
$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
* & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 \\
3 & 3 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 4 \\
4 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\
5 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
\tag1
\end{array}$$
For every $i\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, the position:
$$i*j=\sigma_i(j) \tag2$$
defines the permutation $\sigma_i\in S_5$. From $(1)$ and $(2)$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&\sigma_1=() \\
&\sigma_2=(12345) \\
&\sigma_3=(13542) \\
&\sigma_4=(143)(25) \\
&\sigma_5=(15324) \\
\tag3
\end{alignat}
Now to the associativity. From $(2)$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&i*(j*k)=(i*j)*k &\iff \\
&i*\sigma_j(k)=\sigma_i(j)*k &\iff \\
&\sigma_i(\sigma_j(k))=\sigma_{\sigma_i(j)}(k) &\iff \\
&(\sigma_i\sigma_j)(k)=\sigma_{\sigma_i(j)}(k) &\iff \\
&\sigma_i\sigma_j=\sigma_{\sigma_i(j)} \\
\end{alignat}

Therefore, the Latin Square is associative if and only if, for every $i,j,k$:
$$i*j=k\Longrightarrow \sigma_i\sigma_j=\sigma_k \tag4$$
For your Latin Square, the associativity test $(4)$ fails -for example- with $(i,j,k)=(2,3,4)$; in fact, from $(1)$:
$$2*3=4$$
but from $(3)$:
$$\sigma_2\sigma_3=(143)\ne\sigma_4$$

That said, it's fair noting that this routine is not in general more efficient than going directly through the calculation of (possibly all) the triplets.